# Looping through csv in PHP - inserting and updating

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am looping through a csv in PHP and updating a mysql database with the data. When running my code it inserts the same data 800 times and then moves on to the next record. Once it reaches the second record it seems to insert each row as a row in the DB as it's supposed to.

Do I have an error in the loop(possibly an infinite loop) that mysql might just be correcting for?

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('parsetest', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use parsetest : ' . mysql_error());
}

function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}

$data = csv_to_array('stockimp.csv');

foreach ($data as $key) {

    $style = $key['Style'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stocklink2 WHERE Style = '$style'");
    if($result === FALSE) { 
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE stocklink2 SET Style = '$style' ");
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query on update: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        else {
            echo $key['Style']." Updated <br>";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stocklink2 (Style) VALUES ('$style') ");
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query on insert: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        else {
            echo $key['Style']." Inserted <br>";    
        }

    }


}
```

Update:

The original problem was solved. The table did not have any columns set to unique, once I changed the first column of the table to "unique" the records inserted in sequence.

The update part of the loop now fails Duplicate entry '2'.

Comment: This should be quite easy to debug.  Try using `echo` or `print_r` (followed by an `exit` if needed) to find out more about what's going on in your loops.

Comment: Try printing response from this function $data = csv_to_array('stockimp.csv'); to see if data is correct.

Comment: Please check mysqli and prepared statements. They'll give you a huge performance boost when running these queries.

Answer (score 0):

The original problem was solved. The table did not have any columns set to unique, once I changed the first column of the table to "unique" the records inserted in sequence.

The update part of the loop then failed with Duplicate entry '2'.
The final working solution:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('parsetest', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}


/*===============================================
=            Generate array from csv            =
===============================================*/

function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}

$data = csv_to_array('stockimp.csv');

foreach ($data as $key) {

    //set and print style
    $style = $key['Style'];
    $id = $key['Rec No'];
    echo $style."<br><br>";

    // See if the style exists
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stocklink2 WHERE 'Rec No' = '$id'");
    print_r($result);
    // if there's an error, die
    if($result === FALSE) { 
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    // else do this
    else{
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stocklink2 (`Rec No`,`Style`) VALUES ('$id','$style') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Style = '$style'; ");

    }

}
```

This is not the optimal solution as mysqli and prepared statements can still be added.